# Best way to proceed to have both public and private routes on a single web app using Keycloak and React router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, keycloak

I had a web app where you had to be authentified to see the content. First thing you saw entering the website was the Keycloak login page rendered in **Login.js**, once you were logged in, you had access to **Routes.js**. Now I have to add public routes to this same application and I'm not sure how to proceed. Here's what I have so far.

**Index.js**

```
  <Suspense fallback='loading'>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <PublicRoutes/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Suspense>
```

**PublicRoutes.js**

```
    return ( 
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/signup"/>}
            />
            <Route exact path="/signup" render={() => <SignupPage header={HeaderNav}/>}
            />
            <Route exact path="/login" render={() => <Login/>}
            />
        </Switch>
    );
```

**Login.js**

```
if(this.state.keycloak) {
  if(this.state.authenticated) return (
    <Routes keycloak={this.state.keycloak}/>
  ); else return (<div>Unable to authenticate!</div>)
}
return (
  <div>Loading, please wait...</div>
);
```

**Routes.js**

```
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/home"/>}
            />
            <Route exact path="/home" render={() => <HomePage header={HeaderNav} sidebar={Sidebar}/>}
            />
            <Route exact path="/catalog" render={() => <CatalogPage header={HeaderNav} sidebar={Sidebar}/>}
            />
            <Route exact path="/query" render={() => <QueryPage header={HeaderNav} sidebar={Sidebar}/>}
            />
            <Route exact path="/workshop" render={() => <WorkshopPage header={HeaderNav} sidebar={Sidebar}/>}
            />
            <Route exact path="/dashboard/stats" render={() => <StatsPage header={HeaderNav} sidebar={Sidebar} keycloak={this.props.keycloak}/>}
            />
            <Route exact path="/dashboard/keys" render={() => <KeysPage header={HeaderNav} sidebar={Sidebar} keycloak={this.props.keycloak}/>}
            />
            <Route exact path="/dashboard/consumption" render={() => <ConsumptionPage header={HeaderNav} sidebar={Sidebar} keycloak={this.props.keycloak}/>}
            />
            <Route exact path="/faq" render={() => <HelpPage header={HeaderNav} sidebar={Sidebar}/>}
            />
            <Route exact path="/contact_us" render={() => <ContactPage header={HeaderNav} sidebar={Sidebar}/>}
            />
            <Redirect from="/login" to="/home"/>
        </Switch>
```

What I'd like is that the Routes.js file takes over the PublicRoutes.js file when the user is authentified. Right now, when the user logs in, he can still only see the public routes content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try lifting state up. Maybe `Index.js` can switch between 2 sets of routers?

You can pass state (Keycloak object) or callbacks (handleLogin) for Login.js if you need to

Example:

```
render() {
   const { keycloak, authenticated } = this.state;
   return 

   <div>
     {authenticated ? (
       <Secured keycloak={keycloak} />
      ) : (
       <Public handleLogin={this.handleLogin} />
     )}
   </div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've managed to make it work using your solution.

Comment: Using your solution, how can I prevent the index state to be reverted back to default on browser refresh?

Comment: You can persist the state of the application in the localStorage using browser localStorage API. Or use one of the many available wrappers on npm like `local-storage`